# How can I use a Angular variable as part of an iframe src url?

Tags: angular

Hi and thanks for your help.

I'm building a Ionic app using Angular. One of the tabs of the app should dynamically load a specific webpage on a specific date. I am using an iframe, but I am struggling to integrate the date (the variable "today", appropriately formatted) into the src URL:

```
   <iframe src="[first part of the url]{{today | date: 'dd_MM_yyyy'}}.html"
    width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen sandbox></iframe>
```

does not work, while it works perfectly if I use the same src string, for example, in a  tag.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: look at the HTML in the browser and see what the actual value of the SRC attribute is.  I expect you need to use the sanitizer

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe [src]="url"
  ....
```

url is a variable name, i'm not sure it works.